# Inheritance in iterable implementation of python's multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, subclass, iterable

I found the default implementation of python's `multiprocessing.Queue` lacking, in that it's not iterable like any other collection. So I went about the effort of creating a 'subclass' of it, adding the feature in. As you can see from the code below, it's not a proper subclass, as `multiprocess.Queue` isn't a direct class itself, but a factory function, and the real underlying class is `multiprocess.queues.Queue`. I don't have the understanding nor effort to expend necessary to go about mimicking the factory function just so I can inherit from the class properly, so I simply had the new class create it's own instance from the factory and treat it as the superclass. Here is the code;

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue, Value, Lock
import queue

class QueueClosed(Exception):
    pass

class IterableQueue:
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        self.closed = Value('b', False)
        self.close_lock = Lock()
        self.queue = Queue(maxsize)

    def close(self):
        with self.close_lock:
            self.closed.value = True
            self.queue.close()

    def put(self, elem, block=True, timeout=None):
        with self.close_lock:
            if self.closed.value:
                raise QueueClosed()
            else:
                self.queue.put(elem, block, timeout)

    def put_nowait(self, elem):
        self.put(elem, False)

    def get(self, block=True):
        if not block:
            return self.queue.get_nowait()
        elif self.closed.value:
            try:
                return self.queue.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                return None
        else:
            val = None
            while not self.closed.value:
                try:
                    val = self.queue.get_nowait()
                    break
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass
            return val

    def get_nowait(self):
        return self.queue.get_nowait()

    def join_thread(self):
        return self.queue.join_thread()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        val = self.get()
        if val == None:
            raise StopIteration()
        else:
            return val

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()
```

This allows me to instantiate an `IterableQueue` object just like a normal `multiprocessing.Queue`, put elements into it like normal, and then inside child consumers, simply loop over it like so;

```py
from iterable_queue import IterableQueue
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
import os

def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def consumer(queue):
    print(f"[{os.getpid()}] Consuming")
    for i in queue:
        print(f"[{os.getpid()}] < {i}")
        n = fib(i)
        print(f"[{os.getpid()}] {i} > {n}")
    print(f"[{os.getpid()}] Closing")

def producer():
    print("Enqueueing")
    with IterableQueue() as queue:
        procs = [Process(target=consumer, args=(queue,)) for _ in range(cpu_count())]
        [p.start() for p in procs]
        [queue.put(i) for i in range(36)]
    print("Finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    producer()
```

and it works almost seamlessly; the consumers exit the loop once the queue has been closed, but only after exhausting all remaining elements. However, I was unsatisfied with the lack of inherited methods. In an attempt to mimic actual inheritance behavior, I tried adding the following meta function call to the class;

```py
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in self.__dict__:
        return self.__dict__[name]
    else:
        return self.queue.__getattr__[name]
```

However, this fails when instances of the `IterableQueue` class are manipulated inside child `multiprocessing.Process` threads, as the class's `__dict__` property is not preserved within them. I attempted to remedy this in a hacky manner by replacing the class's default `__dict__` with a `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`, like so;

```py
def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
    self.closed = Value('b', False)
    self.close_lock = Lock()
    self.queue = Queue(maxsize)
    self.__dict__ = Manager().dict(self.__dict__)
```

However on doing so, I received an error stating `RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`. So my question is, how should I go about inheriting from the Queue class properly such that the subclass has inherited access to all of it's properties? In addition, while the queue is empty but not closed, the consumers all sit in a busy loop instead of a true IO block, taking up valuable cpu resources. If you have any suggestions on concurrency and race condition issues I might run into with this code, or how I might solve the busy loop issue, I'd be willing to take suggestions therein as well.

---

Based on code provided by MisterMiyagi, I created this general purpose `IterableQueue` class which can accept arbitrary input, blocks properly, and does not hang on queue close;

```py
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
from multiprocessing import get_context

class QueueClosed(Exception):
    pass

class IterableQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0, *, ctx=None):
        super().__init__(
            maxsize=maxsize,
            ctx=ctx if ctx is not None else get_context()
        )

    def close(self):
        super().put((None, False))
        super().close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.get()
        except QueueClosed:
            raise StopIteration

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result, is_open = super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        if not is_open:
            super().put((None, False))
            raise QueueClosed
        return result

    def put(self, val, *args, **kwargs):
        super().put((val, True), *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()
```

Comment: What kind of manipulations do you need to do on ``IterableQueue`` instances? Do you set attributes in one process and read them in another? What is the use-case behind this?

Comment: I't primarily a more streamlined approach to producer-consumer schemas. I can start up a consumer thread, have it sit in an iterable loop over the queue for it's entire action, and as long as elements are provided it'll continue consuming them. Then once it finishes, it automatically exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multiprocess.Queue` wrapper only serves to [use the default context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_context).

```
def Queue(self, maxsize=0):
    '''Returns a queue object'''
    from .queues import Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
```

When inheriting, you can replicate this in the `__init__` method. This allows you to inherit the entire `Queue` behaviour. You only need to add the iterator methods:

```
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
from multiprocessing import get_context


class IterableQueue(Queue):
    """
    ``multiprocessing.Queue`` that can be iterated to ``get`` values

    :param sentinel: signal that no more items will be received
    """
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0, *, ctx=None, sentinel=None):
        self.sentinel = sentinel
        super().__init__(
            maxsize=maxsize,
            ctx=ctx if ctx is not None else get_context()
        )

    def close(self):
        self.put(self.sentinel)
        # wait until buffer is flushed...
        while self._buffer:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        # before shutting down the sender
        super().close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        result = self.get()
        if result == self.sentinel:
            # re-queue sentinel for other listeners
            self.put(result)
            raise StopIteration
        return result
```

Note that the `sentinel` to indicate end-of-queue is compared by equality, because identity is not preserved across processes. The often-used `queue.Queue` sentinel `object()` does not work properly with this.

Comment: I used your code with the example producer-consumer code I have in my question as a demonstration, and when the consumers reach the end of the queue, they hang instead of exiting. No exception is raised on `Queue.close()`.

Comment: FYI, I'm running the code in an Ubuntu shell within WSL on Windows 10, in case that's important.

Comment: @Maurdekye I will have to check. Will let you know once there is an updated version.

Comment: @Maurdekye ``close`` now pushes in an explicit sentinel object. This works on any OS that supports ``Queue`` in the first place.

Comment: Will this handle the above case where there are multiple consumers listening on the queue?

Comment: @Maurdekye Now it does. Readers do not permanently consume the shutdown signal.

Comment: I may alter the code to force interaction through the use of tuples, allowing a pair of values and `isclosed` to be given on put/get, allowing any arbitrary sentinel. But otherwise, this seems to address all the issues I had previously. I'll give it a check, and after confirming I'll select your answer.

Comment: After testing, it seems like this solution still hangs once the queue is emptied. Can you maybe test your code with the example I posted before posting changes to it in future?

Comment: @Maurdekye I did, it shuts down fine. Do you see all processes `Closing`? Do you see the last message, `35 > 9227465`?

Comment: In addition, there's no way you tested it using my code, since your function doesn't include the `__enter__` and `__exit__` context management functions necessary for the `with` statement in the producer to function.

Comment: Wait, nevermind that last comment; I think I set up the program wrong last time, and broke some functionality. It worked this time.

Comment: @Maurdekye I am not interested in bickering. Here is the test code I am using: https://gist.github.com/maxfischer2781/51d49519a100b5487416e011c9fb20f6

Comment: After some extensive use, I found a flaw in this code; occasionally, when `close` is called, a separate thread will throw a `BrokenPipeError` that can't be caught. I created a temporary hack around this by throwing a short 0.1s sleep in between the final `self.put(self.sentinel)` and the `super().close()` lines, but I couldn't figure out a better, long term solution to the issue.

Comment: Note that this is a general feature of ``Queue.close`` - it does not wait for items to be sent. I have expanded the sample code with a dynamically adjusted ``sleep`` until all items are sent.